# How can I access mobile front camera and record a video in Js?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a app with: Html, Css and Javascript, and I want that app access mobile front camera and record a video off the user face, I am usin Adobe Phone Gap to convert my codes to .apk

Have similar questions in StackOverflow about this, but anyone couldn't help me, I've tried searching in Google, but I found nothing

I've tried made this:

```
navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                         navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                         navigator.mozGetUserMedia;

if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: { width: 1280, height: 720 } },
      function(stream) {
         var video = document.querySelector('video');
         video.srcObject = stream;
         video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
           video.play();
         };
      },
      function(err) {
         console.log("The following error occurred: " + err.name);
      }
   );
} else {
   console.log("getUserMedia not supported");
}
```

but don't work

I expect, when the user click in a button, the app will open the front cam, and the user record a video of your face.

Comment: "_don't work_" is not a problem description. What does it actually do? What behavior do you see? What errors do you get?

Comment: MediaDevices API allows you to select: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2018/04/choosing-cameras-javascript-mediadevices-api.html

Comment: `navigator.getUserMedia` is deprecated. Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/getUserMedia

Answer (score 4):

You can use`<input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera">`  to access the user camera from a Browser

Comment: +1, this is a solid answer.  Very often people try to re-implement handling of video when really just letting the default camera app do it is a far better solution.  This is usually the best, for compatibility, for usability, and for quality.

Answer (score 2):

The `capture` attribute on file inputs (`input type="file"`) can be used to activate photo (`accept="image/*"`) or video (`accept="video/*"`) mode on the front (`capture="user"`) or rear (`capture="user"`) camera.

Note:

- Test the code on mobile devices for best results. Desktop environments may show the standard file picker only.
- Supporting webcams on desktop environments can be far more tricky: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Taking_still_photos

```html
<input type="file" id="soundFile" capture="user" accept="audio/*"><br/>
<input type="file" id="videoFile" capture="environment" accept="video/*"><br/>
<input type="file" id="imageFile" capture="user" accept="image/*">
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/capture